# log4j in Spring - Hibernate Idea project

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I'm using Java Spring and currently site works absolutely correct

please see source files here https://github.com/VadOs1/shop-spring-hibernate

the problem comes when I try to implement logging using log4j

I add Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I add log4j.properties file to src/main/resources folder

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/server/webapps/my.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

until this my application compiles correct and all is ok

the problem occures when I try using log4j somewhere in controller class for example

```
...
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MainController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/robots.txt", produces = {"text/plain"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public String getRobotsTxt() {
            LOG.error("Want to see this message in my log file");
            return SEOService.getRobotsTxt();
        }
    }
```

the whole app never compiles and I get these errors:

```
03-Dec-2015 11:31:59.001 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController' defined in file [C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\com\gmail\dissa\vadim\controllers\MainController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.gmail.dissa.vadim.controllers.MainController
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:535)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:694)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:399)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.gmail.dissa.vadim.controllers.MainController
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1088)
    ... 37 more

03-Dec-2015 11:31:59.007 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController' defined in file [C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\com\gmail\dissa\vadim\controllers\MainController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.gmail.dissa.vadim.controllers.MainController
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:535)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:694)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:399)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.gmail.dissa.vadim.controllers.MainController
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1088)
    ... 37 more
...
```

Comment: is it working without this line `private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MainController.class);` ?

Comment: sure. it works fine when I inject Maven dependency and add log4j.properties file. when I add  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MainController.class); and then use it LOG.error("Want to see this message in my log file"); it brakes

Comment: obviously it COMPILED! it is run time error.  Is the stack trace complete? Are there any other causes following?  It is essential to show what is actually missing

Comment: I suspect the log4j JAR is not packaged with your WAR.  Can you verify by `mvn dependency:tree` and also extracting your resulting WAR?

Comment: thank you Adrian. you are absolutely right. there is no log4j.jar in resulting WAR but unfortunatelly I can't get how this can happen. could you please advise how I can fix this

Comment: issue closed )) finally works )) thank you again Adrian

Comment: so what's the reason? wrong dependencies set?

Comment: I bet your scope of dependency is set wrong somewhere (e.g. set to provided)?

Comment: it is even easier in fact )) Idea -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Output Layout -> Move available elements to war file ))

Comment: now overcoming new log4j challange )) will appreciate your help as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069601/log4j-log-file-access-ubuntu-tomcat

Comment: issue closed. thanks to all