# log4j log file access Ubuntu (Tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, log4j

I'm using log4j library in my Java Spring Project

When I run my web app on my local Windows machine everything goes ok.

When I deploy my application to Digital Ocean Ubuntu server I get runtime error which I can't fix

`logj4.properties` file which I use for windows and everything runs ok

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\TMP\\log_file.log
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

and `logj4.properties` file which I use for ubuntu and get runtime error

```
  log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
        log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
        log4j.appender.file.File=\\tmp\\log_file.log
        log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
        log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
        log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

ERROR

> log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
>           java.io.FileNotFoundException: TMP\log_file.log (Permission denied)

Does anyone know how to overcome this error?

Comment: Unix uses forward slashes in the path, `TMP\log_file.log` should be `TMP/log_file.log`. No idea whether Digital Ocean even *allows* writing logs to arbitrary location, though.

Comment: Thank you. Forward slashes don't help ((

Comment: the most interesting is that application successfully creates empty log_file.log which is available for modifications from console and than crashes. will appreciate much any advise. thank you

Comment: already posted to digital ocean community but will appreciate much your help as well. thank you

Comment: solution is very simple as it often happens ))  ./logs/my_log.log )) + never put your app compiled with jdk 8 on tomcat 7 server )) thanks again. issue closed

Comment: I have same issue with Ubuntu machine and TomEE server ? I am unable to find solution .